Sanity check for a proof conserning outwards pointing normal vector on the boundary of a closed tubular neighborhood.
From Madsen and Tornehave book ''From calculus to cohomology'' in the proof for theorem 11.27.
Let $M$ an embedded (smooth) closed submanifold $M^n\subset \mathbb R^{n+k}$ and a vector field $X$ on $M$. We define a vector field $F\colon N\to \mathbb R^{n+k}$ by $F(q)=X(\pi(q))+q-\pi(q)$, where $N$ is an open tubular neighborhood of $M$ with the tubular neighborhood projection $\pi\colon N\to M$. Also we have that $N_\varepsilon\subset N\subset\mathbb R^{n+k}$ where $N_\varepsilon$ a closed tubular neighborhood of constant radius $\varepsilon$. If $q\in\partial N_\varepsilon $, the authors claim that $q-\pi(q)$ points in the outwards direction normal to $T_q\partial N_\varepsilon$.
I cannot figure out why $q-\pi(q)$ points is an outwards pointing normal. I know that $\partial N_\varepsilon $ has the induced boundary orientation (for example found it Stokes' theorem).
Outwards pointing in this book is defined as follows. If $N$ is a codimension zero submanifold with a smooth boundary, a tangent vector $w\in T_pM$ at a boundary point $p\in\partial N$ is said to be outward pointing if there exists a chart $(U,h)$ around $p$ with $h(U\cap N)=h(U)\cap ((-\infty,0]\times\mathbb R^{n-1})$ where $D_ph(w)\in\mathbb R^n$ has positive first coordinate.

Your question reduces to examining the case when $M = U\subset \Bbb R^n\times {0}\subset\Bbb R^{n+k}$, so $N=U\times\Bbb R^k$.
